# Crack Linux password if you have plaintext and hash?

Tags: passwords, linux, brute-force

I have a relatively old Linux system, where password are not shadowed, therefore stored in /etc/passwd/.

My question is, since I know the cleartext password, and its hash (looking at the passwd file), Can I quickly figure out the hashing system/crack it? So I would be able to get the cleartext password from another user just from its hash, or at least make bruteforcing faster?

Thanks.

EDIT: The hash is 13 characters long

Comment: here you have your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836468/linux-old-passwd-file-reversing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are one-way algorithms which will help you confirm if a hash of plaintext matches the hash in your possession (the rainbow tables approach that @TTT suggests). It will, however, not help you reverse-crack it.

If the hash function itself turns out to be weak (like MD5/SHA1), you can possibly find strings which collide with the hashes in your possession, creating an alternative password.

Answer (score 3):

The hashing algorithm used is not part of the secret. The hashing algorithm should always be assumed to be known. You can read up to this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

In fact, the string you find in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow` tells you which hash has been used right in the first number:

```
$1 → md5
$2 → blowfish
$2 → eksblowfish
$5 → sha256
$6 → sha512
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help you determine which hashing algorithm is used, but it will not help you brute force other passwords faster. When you brute force you will be calculating *many* hashes. Starting with knowing 0 versus 1 hash doesn't make a difference. Even starting with a rainbow table of trillions of known hashes won't help if the salts are all different.